# Layout de adaptador personalizado pierde el tamaño ANDROID

Tags: android, layout

Estoy creando un adaptador personalizado para un recyclerView y dentro de la vista de android Studio me lo muestra correctamente como muestro la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, cuando recojo los datos desde la BD SQL y los inserto en el layout este se ajusta al tamaño del texto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo soluciono esto? ¿Hay alguna forma de que no se pierda el diseño dado al establecer el texto?

PD: El codigo XML de la vista es el siguiente:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/aceptar">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/callePen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Calle y Num"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fechaEntregadoPen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Fecha Entregado"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:background="@color/cancelar">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/localidadPen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Localidad"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoriaPen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Categoria"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@color/aceptar">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prioridadPen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="NORMAL"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Añade mas codigo y menos imagenes, de esa forma se te podra ayudar de mejor forma.

Comment: Supongo que esos 3 LinearLayout verticales los tendrás anidado dentro de uno horizontal. Si es así enseña el código de ese en cuestión.

Comment: Lo tengo puesto, pero no me deja mostarlo, te lo dejo por aqui: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="5">

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta que el contenedor que alberga o manda llamar a este LinearLayout Horizontal, no le das todo el ancho disponible de la pestaña. También otra cosa, con que pongas los pesos ' android:layout_weight="2"' en cada uno de los Linear Verticales es suficiente, les das a los respectivos textview un ancho de match_parent y como alto wrap_content y te hará la misma función de mejor manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución es agregar un contenedor general para que las 3 vistas (`LinearLayouts`) tengan la misma altura, agrega también a cada `LinearLayout` dentro de este contenedor   `android:layout_height="match_parent"` :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ...
        ...
```

Tendrías como resultado algo similar a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este sería el layout con el cambio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="5">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/cancelar">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/callePen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Calle y Num"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fechaEntregadoPen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Fecha Entregado"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:background="@color/cancelar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/localidadPen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Localidad"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoriaPen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Categoria"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="@color/cancelar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prioridadPen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="NORMAL"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Al parecer la solución para que los weight funcionaran correctamente era añadir ese contenedor global. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, el texto ya no se descoloca.